# Creating editable GridviewColumn with DataTempülate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, gridviewcolumn

I have an observable collection bound to my ListView via its ItemsSource property.
I use a GridView to present the items in the ListView.
By setting the "IsServiceMode" property to "true" in my ViewModel (DataContext to UserControl that houses the ListView) i want to change a GridViewColumn to use TextBox instead of Textblock.
I'm using CellTemplates with ContentControl and DataTemplate as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577870/wpf-gridview-column-and-dynamic-cell-template-based-upon-data-value)

However, the "Binding Position" in the Textblock and Textbox controls don't seem to work although the Editor is suggesting "Position". Position is a property of the items in the bound ObservableCollection and can be used via DisplayMemberBinding without Problems.

**My GridViewColumn**

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Position">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <ContentControl.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsServiceMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsServiceMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Position}"/>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ContentControl.Style>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>´´´
```

Comment: Instead of all this you could use a textbox and bind read only or even enabled property to IsServiceMode? Also it would simplify your xaml by a lot.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Yeah, but the Textbox looks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The Datagrid comes with edit mode. IsReadOnly is turned on and off.
- itemSource must be implemented INotifyCollectionChanged when editing mode is enabled.Like the ObservableCollection

Demo

```
        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="DataGrid1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableCollection}"
            IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsServiceMode}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Path=Position,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```